# Countifs from Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I am trying to make a countifs formula across multiple worksheets.

The formula I have so far is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&TabList&"'!$AG$6:$AI$31"),"1"),INDIRECT("'"&TabList&"'!$AG$6:$AI$31"),"D5")
```

Each of the countifs work seperately but when I put them together they keep coming up with an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you need the ' at the beginning of `"'!$AG$6:$AI$31"` and what is your _Tablist_?

Comment: Tablist is just a range I have set up which holds all the numbers of the sheets I have in the workbook. It worked with countif, just not when I introduce countifs with multiple criteria.